# How To Revert Changes made by Some User in GIT Repository

Tags: git, github, git-svn, git-revert

I have one GIT repository in which a number of users (Say A, B, .....X) committed the file.
I want to delete or revert all the files which are committed by the User 'X'.

Is it possible or do I have to do that manually?

Comment: What is "the file"? Is there a particular file that needs reverts, or do you want to get rid of all of that user's commits?

Comment: Yah in short we need to revert all the changes made by X user. Just like applying a patch which will revert the changes without affecting other user commits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
git log --author=X --format="%H" | xargs git revert
```

The first part of the pipeline produces all SHA1s of commits where the username matches the regular expression (!) `X`; the second part calls a `git revert` on those commits. If one of the commits fails to revert cleanly, though, you might want to just walk through the output of

```
git log --author=X --oneline
```

and revert by hand.

Comment: I recommend putting in a commit limiting range like `git log --author=X 1234fde...master`  And unfortunately, if the changes are significant enough to revert, then you'll probably end up needing to revert each one by hand and resolve conflicts along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you can use git revert for this. See the [git manual section](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#reverting-a-commit) on this for more information.

The gist is that you can say:

git revert 
Where  is the id of the commit you'd like to undo, and it will try to undo it.